# Spring MVC always redirecting to root folder '/'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4 MVC app. When I try to access any URL the application always redirects to the root folder.

My main class:

```
public class SiteMain implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.setConfigLocation("com.mj.cchp.MvcConfig");
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

and MVC Config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/WEB-INF/site.xml" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```